# Setting proxy url for larger request

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When I query for larger features I get `esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl is not set` error. Can someone please explain why proxyurl is needed, how I should set it up, what should it point to, and any other relevant information about it? I am running Websphere and IBM http server.

Comment: This is really four questions, and the last is an open ended one.

Comment: I don't see why this question has been closed as too broad. Using a proxy in a JavaScript application is quite a simple thing to understand, and all the required information is present on a single page which @JohnGravois has linked in his answer. There are several question on the need of a proxy in OpenLayers (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27729/, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24250/), and if those are valid questions, then so is this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the article below explains the purpose of proxies in the Esri JS API and the steps to deploy them.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html